# WCF svc Hosted IIS7 Selfsigned Certificate usage

Tags: wcf, ssl

Designed a svc that will be intermittently consumed by one known customer application across the internet.
Know next to nothing about security so started digging.
Figuring from what I have found;
SSL security transport layer fits.
Self Signed certificate and send public key to client is required.

Am I on the right track or is there a flaw in my logic.
thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track

A SSL Certificate helps you do two things:

- That the client knows who the server is
- That the communication between the client and the server is encrypted

With a self signed certificate you are not sure who signed the certificate, but it works fine for encryption.

The client must trust the certificate, so with a self signed, the client must place the certificate in its list of trusted certificates.